# Backbone View not selecting element

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

This is my first time create a view with Backbone, but I'm not able to render changes to an existing element in the document.

```
var ParamsView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $('#node-parameters'),

    initialize: function() {
        console.log('WOW');
    },

    render: function() {
        console.log('doing it');
        console.log(this.$el.length);
        console.log($('#node-parameters').length);
        this.$el.append('<span>hello world!</span>');
        return this;
    }

});

    var v = new ParamsView();
    v->render();
```

The words `hello world!` do not appear in the target `div`.

The console outputs the following when the view is rendered.

```
WOW
doing it
0
1
```

So I know that my jQuery selector `$('#node-parameters')` is finding 1 DOM element, but the view is not use it.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:** In the JS debugger I can see that `this.el` is undefined for the view.

Comment: Could you try `var v = new ParamsView({el: '#node-parameters'});` ?

Comment: @nikoshr That works! I wonder why?

Comment: Explanation incoming in a few minutes:)

Comment: My code works now if I change el to just a string, and not a jQuery selector.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini el is supposed to be an HTML element, $el contains the jQuery element (however, I think if you use `new ParamsView({el: '$(#node-parameters')});` it will work, as the constructor will change it to an HTML element).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is probably equivalent to this :

```
var ParamsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#node-parameters'),

    initialize: function() {
        console.log('WOW');
    },

    render: function() {
        console.log('doing it');
        console.log(this.$el.length);
        console.log($('#node-parameters').length);
        this.$el.append('<span>hello world!</span>');
        return this;
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var v = new ParamsView();
    v.render();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/mNprr/

Notice that you class is declared before the *DOM ready event*.

You set the el at extend time with `$('#node-parameters')`. `$` is a function that is immediately executed but, and that's why you get an undefined element, #node-parameters does not exist at that point.

By injecting the element with `new ParamsView({el: '#node-parameters'})`, you set a valid el after the DOM ready event. You could also set it via

```
var ParamsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#node-parameters'
});
```

`el` is then evaluated when you instantiate your class, after the DOM ready event. http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/mNprr/1/

Comment: Actually my code is executed after document.ready via an AJAX requestion. $('#node-parameters').length will be 1 before calling `new ParamsView()`. Still, using a string fixed the problem.